# Generate If Statements in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to create a synthesizable, parametrized priority encoder in Verilog. Specifically, I want to find the least significant 1 in a vector and return a vector containing just that 1. For example:

```
IN[3:0] | OUT[4:0]
--------+---------
1010    | 00010
1111    | 00001
0100    | 00100
0000    | 10000   (special case)
```

So if the vectors are four bits wide, the code is:

```
if (in[0]==1'b1) least_one = 1;
else if (in[1]==1'b1) least_one = 2;
else if (in[2]==1'b1) least_one = 4;
else if (in[3]==1'b1) least_one = 8;
else out = 16; // special case in==0, set carry bit
```

I need a general, scalable way to do this because the input/output vector length is parametrized. My current code is:

```
module least_one_onehot
#(parameter ADDR_WIDTH=4)
(output reg [ADDR_WIDTH:0] least_one,
input [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] in);

genvar i;

always @(in) begin
    if (in[0]==1'b1) least_one = 1;
    generate for (i=1; i<ADDR_WIDTH; i=i+1) begin : U 
        else if (in[i]==1'b1) least_one = 2**i; 
        end 
        endgenerate
    else least_one = 2**ADDR_WIDTH;
    end

endmodule
```

When I try to compile this, I receive the following errors:

```
file: least_one_onehot.v
        generate for (i=1; i<ADDR_WIDTH; i=i+1) begin : U
               |
ncvlog: *E,GIWSCP (least_one_onehot.v,10|8): Generated instantiation can only be valid within a module scope [12.1.3(IEEE 2001)].
                        else if (in[i]==1'b1) least_one = 2**i; 
                           |
ncvlog: *E,NOTSTT (least_one_onehot.v,11|6): expecting a statement [9(IEEE)].
                endgenerate
                          |
ncvlog: *E,GIWSCP (least_one_onehot.v,13|12): Generated instantiation can only be valid within a module scope [12.1.3(IEEE 2001)].
                else least_one = 2**ADDR_WIDTH;
                   |
ncvlog: *E,NOTSTT (least_one_onehot.v,14|5): expecting a statement [9(IEEE)]
```

I've tried various arrangements of the generate, if, and always statements, all without success. Anyone know the proper syntax for this? Case-statement implementation or other alternatives would also be fine. Thanks.

Comment: There's a difference between procedural contexts and module contexts. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443368/unknown-verilog-error-expecting-endmodule/10449997#10449997) answer.

Comment: Out should be one-bit wider than in to accommodate all-zero case. I've clarified the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how generate works.  It isn't a text pre-processor that emits the code in between the generate/endgenerate pair with appropriate substitutions.  You have to have complete syntactic entities withing the pair.  I don't have access to a simulator right this minute but this might do the trick for you (totally untested)

```
genvar i;
generate
    for (i = 1; i < ADDR_WIDTH; i = i + 1) begin : U
        least_one[i] = in[i] & ~|in[i - 1:0];
    end
endgenerate
least_one[0] = in[0];
least_one[ADDR_WIDTH] = ~|in;
```

Ordinarily Verilog would complain about the non-constant bit slice width but since it's within a generate loop it might work.

Failing something like the above you just test for the first set bit in a for-loop and then decode that result.

Comment: You need to prefix `assign` to all the `least_one[N] =` statements. Otherwise, your code looks like it will compile correctly.

Comment: @Brian Magnuson: One inefficiency in this code (that becomes apparent when `ADDR_WIDTH` becomes large) is that its size is O(N log N) where N=`ADDR_WIDTH`. The calculation of `least_one` can be very easily formulated as a [parallel prefix computation](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/parallelPrefix.html) which makes the size of the design O(N). Basically, it exploits the fact that the terms `|in[i-1:0]` have much logic in common.

Comment: When I face a problem like this (especially when the bit width is large), where it is hard to write the parallel prefix computation logic in a `generate` statement, I use a (parameterized) Perl script to generate the SystemVerilog code and invoke it in a Makefile before I compile for simulation or synthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* need a generate block. You could use:

```
integer i;
reg found;
always @(in) begin
  least_one = {(ADDR_WIDTH+1){1'b0}};
  found = 1'b0;
  for (i=0; i<ADDR_WIDTH; i=i+1) begin
    if (in[i]==1'b1 && found==1'b0) begin
      least_one[i] = 1'b1;
      found = 1'b1;
    end
  end
  least_one[ADDR_WIDTH] = (found==1'b0);
end
```

If you really want to use a generate block, then you need to assign each bit.

```
assign least_one[0] = in[0];
assign least_one[ADDR_WIDTH] = (in == {ADDR_WIDTH{1'b0}});
genvar i;
generate
  for (i=1; i<ADDR_WIDTH; i=i+1) begin : U
    assign least_one[i] = in[i] && (in[i - 1:0] == {i{1'b0}});
  end
endgenerate
```

Comment: True, I don't require a generate statement. Anything synthesizable that gets the job done is fine.

Answer (score 1):

This simulates the way you want it to, but it is not synthesizable (you didn't specify if that was a requirement):

```
module least_one_onehot #(parameter ADDR_WIDTH=4) (
    output reg [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] least_one,
    input      [ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] in
);

always @* begin
    least_one = '0;
    for (int i=ADDR_WIDTH-1; i>=0; i--) begin
        if (in[i]) least_one = 2**i;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Note that it uses SystemVerilog constructs.

Comment: According to the original code (not shown in the truth table), if `in` is all zeros then the MSB of `least_one` needs to be high. Assign the bit before the for-loop and correct your `least_one` range.

Comment: @Greg: I already posted a comment to the OP to clarify the outputs.

Comment: Yes, code needs to be synthesizable. I'd added this requirement to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the following block of code for what you need:
assign out = {1'b1,in} & ((~{1'b1,in})+1);

You could try this (dropping the extra high bit for legibility), but I like to explicitly do the twos compliment to avoid any potential compatibility problems.

assign out = in & (-1*in);